# Excel VBA Hide Calling Cell's Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a custom formula in Excel which will hide the row of the cell it's called from. I have seen lots of examples of hard coding the row to be hidden, but I want this to be based on where the formula is called. Below are my two methods that have not worked but I'm not sure why. What have I missed?

```
Function HideRow(hide As Boolean)
   ' Method 1
   Application.Caller.EntireRow.Hidden = hide
   ' Method 2
   If (hide) Then
       Application.Caller.RowHeight = 0
   Else
       Application.Caller.RowHeight = 20
   End If
   HideRow = hide
End Function
```

Comment: If you are trying to invoke this as a UDF (i.e. use it in a cell as `=HideRow(TRUE)` or similar), the official answer is "A UDF cannot modify the state of Excel - all it can do is return a value to the cell from which it was called."

Comment: `activeCell` is what you want. Disregard that, I didn't think you wanted an UDF. what @YowE3K is right.

Comment: The obvious way around this is to use a `Worksheet_Change` or similar event that watches for changes in whatever it is that you use to decide whether the row should be hidden or not, and then do the hiding/unhiding in that event.

Comment: activeCell is *not* what you want.  `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell` would typically work but since this is a UDF you're out of luck for the reason mentioned by YowE3K

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anyway to do this automatically without having to re-run a filter each time to hide the null rows?

Comment: A lot will depend on how you were intending to calculate the boolean that was to be passed as the parameter to the UDF.  Obviously it isn't going to be a simple `=HideRow(TRUE)`, because that would really annoy the users who would then have to manually unhide the row so that they can change it back to `=HideRow(FALSE)`, so I assume there is something else on the sheet which is calculating whether the row should be hidden or not.  Making that "something else" the target of a `Worksheet_Change` event could allow the hiding to be done as part of that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by YowE3K in the comments, this is not possible through a formula. What I did instead was linked the following script to a button that looks through a given range and hides any row that has the word "Hide" in the representative cell:

```
Sub Submit()
For Each R In Range("HideRowRange")
    If R.Value = "Hide" Then
        R.EntireRow.rowheight = 0
    Else
        R.EntireRow.rowheight = 20
    End If
Next R
End Sub
```